# Droppable doesn't reenable a 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to build an image ranker for 10 images. I want the user to be able to drag the images around to their respective cells and if they change their mind, they can adjust their choices. The idea is not to have more than 1 image in each cell, so I disabled droppable upon drop but I want to re-enable when leaving. What happens now is that it re-enables the first time but not the second time.

This can be recreated if you try to drag an image between two cells multiple times. After the second time it supposedly "re-enables", it will permanently disable, not letting any image be dropped there.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pdrjbb7e/2/

```
$(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    out: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
        console.log("out");
        $(this).prev().droppable("option", "disabled", false);
        $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", false);
    },
    over: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        $(this).prev().droppable("option", "disabled", false);
        $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", false);
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        //var numberElements = droppedOn.children().length+1;
        $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
        $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 10, left: 45 }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }

});
```

I feel like this should work, because I'm enabling upon "out" and "over"?